# What is the definition of “small government” according to the Republican Party?

Tags: united-states, republican-party

When Republican governors banned mask mandates in schools, [many commentators](https://www.theshorthorn.com/opinion/opinion-gov-greg-abbott-s-crusade-against-local-mask-mandates-exposes-his-party-s-hypocrisy/article_c865d1dc-01f2-11ec-90b3-877a21425f12.html) called them out as hypocrites due to such bans violating the concept of “small government”. However this concept can have many definitions:

1. Local self rule wherever possible, letting a small county council handle things without the state or Federal government intervening. However the small county council can pass whatever restrictions they see fit.
2. All rulemaking should be delegated to states whenever possible but not lower than that, so the state itself is the “small government”
3. General lack of regulation wherever possible, letting citizens do whatever they please. This means *any* level of government should pass as little restrictions as possible.
4. As little taxation as possible, so minimal number of government programs funded by tax dollars. This would be a budget focused view, so restrictive rules would still be possible as long as they don’t cost a lot to implement.

Which of those definitions (if any) are the official by the Republican Party currently?

Comment: Related question about Trump specifically: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15200/what-exactly-are-donald-trumps-views-on-small-government. The linked question seems to focus on spending rather than government restrictions.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but I wonder what a good official source would be. There’s the party platform, obviously, but even in the best of times platforms in general seem to be more aspirational that effective, and pretty far from the actual principles that govern the party

Comment: @divibisan various Conservative think tanks might have an exact definition. Usually that’s as close as you get to specifics.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to answer the question. If you would like to answer the question, please post a real answer.

Comment: Ok, down-voters to my now deleted answer: let me ask you this. If a government was limited to members of the GOP, would the GOP call it a "big" government? If equality does not exist in nature, a government cannot (according to the GOP or anyone else) be of exactly the right size, ergo such government must be *small* according to members of the GOP.

Comment: @user189035 if you believe your post should not have been deleted, please raise it on [meta] instead of in the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe you will find an 'official' platform for or definition of 'small government' within the GOP; the phrase is a neoliberal buzzword more than an actual set of policies. Republicans began using the phrase 'small government' regularly back circa the 1980s, adopting it from Libertarians and Free Market economists (both of which were comparatively prominent in the party in that era). The general thread of the idea was that government should maximize *efficiency* and *liberty*, i.e.:

- The elimination of governments waste and pork
- The reduction of government intervention in the private sector to some necessary minimum
- A shift from public services to private enterprises
- A resistance to international activities — military actions, pacts and treaties, international organizations — in favor of private economic solutions

But even back then, the concept was a political ideal, not overly-burdened with specific details or implementations. A nice ideal, or at least an interesting one, but not one that was philosophically or pragmatically developed.

Fairly quickly, however, the 'small government' ideal became entangled with latent segregationist, McCarthyist, and Christian nationalist ideation. Even in Reagan's era, the GOP used the ideal to launch attacks on the welfare and social safety net systems — invoking images of 'welfare mothers' and 'young bucks' (Reagan's term; a slur for black men) living high on purloined tax dollars — and to oppose federal education mandates that prioritized science over religious teachings. The 'small government' rubric lost any connection to the ideals of efficiency or liberty. It became a catch phrase for the preservation of the status quo and the defense of powerful entities against the greater communities they existed within, e.g. Republicans:

- Denounce the wastefulness of social security while demanding ever-increasing expenditures in law enforcement and military sectors
- Reject regulations on private industry, while also rejecting public concerns about pollution and toxic waste
- Assert the privacy and individual rights of religious groups and political elites while attacking the privacy and individual right of women and minority groups.

In the modern GOP, the concept of 'small government' is inseparable from anti-Democratic, anti-progressive, and anti-liberal agendas. It has lost all but the most specious connections to the original Libertarian ideal and only serves to justify an assortment of extremist positions. I doubt the GOP is willing to formulate a proper 'small government' platform or definition because:

1. It is unlikely they could craft a platform that would satisfy all the ways the term is currently used in conservative dialog, at least without appearing completely schizoid
2. Creating such a platform or definition would commit the GOP to a particular agenda which would

   - open a framework for discussion and negotiation that they fear the Democrats could leverage, and
   - limit the usefulness of the term for invoking and justifying political animus among their constituents

The modern GOP doesn't seem to want 'small government' to be an accessible ideal or practical policy point. They want the phrase to be a trigger for outrage that is as generally applicable as possible. They want the term defined in the gut, not in the head; laying out a platform would only spoil its emotional impact.

Comment: Thanks! But to be clear - "small government" never referred to giving more power to counties/cities? The Left's argument that the Republican party is betraying their own ideals by banning local officials from instituting mask mandates. It seems like many understand "small government" as "government of small units", where "unit" should be smaller than the state as a whole. But I've usually seen it argued as a Feds vs. States debate, not a State vs. county one.

Comment: @JonathanReez: the "Small Government" rubric has merged somewhat with the "States' Rights" rubric (which I lump under segregationism, since race has always been the primary driver of "States' Rights" ideation). Generally speaking, the conflict between states and their counties/municipalities is a very recent phenomenon, stemming from Trumpism and its efforts to impose ideology over and above practical reality. It takes half-crazed governors like DeSantis and Abbot to double down on a lie by criminalizing reason and common sense in communities.

Comment: Cool that pretty much confirms my suspicion that “small government” being misused in that particular case.

Answer (score 3):

In US politics, "small government" is a shorthand for lower taxes (both for businesses and individuals), less regulation, and a lower level of programs to assist individuals.

For opponents of the idea, "small government" is heard as a euphemism for trying to defeat efforts to address the nation's growing inequality.

For supporters, as is common, the positions are presented so that individuals, and party sponsors, both hear what they want to hear. De-regulationist policy has been around long enough (with bipartisan support at many critical moments, in spite of Dem. party rhetoric), to arguably say something about how this turns out, and, arguably, shows a puzzling discrepancy.

Working class voters in the US tend to find the "small government" concept appealing, when the overriding issue of race is not in play. This demographic group has in fact seen a reduction of their real income during the time period when the policy-values in question were implemented and took effect. However, this has not been clearly reflected in voter sentiment, at least if "independents" and non-voters are excluded.

The question of the state-vs-federal power balance, while central to US politics, is IMO factored out from the concept invoked by the "small government" term. However "small government" and "states' rights" are usually paired in the strictly binary party grouping that is characteristic of the US.